# Swift Local Notification that repeats on certain dates

Tags: swift, uilocalnotification

Is there a way to create a local notification that repeats only on certain dates. I have an "Important Events" notification and there are about 80 dates that should send this notification, each with a different title. I know for location, you can use `CoreLocation` and the method didEnter/ExitRegion to send a notification even though the application is not running. Is there a way to do that for certain dates? Or do I need to make 80 notifications that all have one trigger?

Comment: If they are separate dates and titles, you need 80 different notifications, each with their own date trigger. However, each app is limited to 64 local notifications being scheduled at once (prioritising the soonest).

Comment: localNotification.fireDate  = Yourdate